# Gmail e-mail address extractor

Tags: php, gmail, google-api, extract

I am looking for a way to extract all the email addresses of all the recipients from my gmail account... I have never worked with the Gmail API so any beginning directions are welcome\

preferably php

Comment: What platform/programming language?

Comment: please have a look at this link [click here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/index.html)

Comment: Theres one at www.starbanana.com which I use every now and then, its simple but does the job well. Saves as a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking at Gmail API, I would recommend to enable IMAP and then do it using IMAP. But this is not a good option if you need to do this on many accounts on enterprise level.

**UPDATE**
Hope "[Using PHP IMAP functions to download email from Gmail](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-download-email-gmail/)" will help you.

Comment: Only one account but how do i do it with imap

Answer (score 1):

[GME](http://starbanana.com) Have a gmail email extractor, it scans the To, from etc... and saves them on your PC as a CSV file.

I also monitored my LAN and it does NOT send anything it shouldn't, so no sneeky harvesting like you find on some.

Overall happy with the results. Simple and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out [MineMyMail](http://minemymail.com/)
It is configurable and extracts email addresses not only from the headers but from the message body as well.

Answer (score 0):

[ReverseApps](http://www.reverseapps.com) having outlook email extractor, if you already configured your gmail account on outlook then using this application you can scan your TO, From, Body of email etc. and easily export to excel.

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: Give some explanation..how to use it?